# How do I remove a fade animation from a hero widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget card that I have wrapped in a Hero.
When I click the card to load a new view, the hero widget is being having a fade animation applied to it.
Does anyone know how to remove this fade animation from the hero? Has anyone else seen this before?
The hero returns to its original position without a fade which looks like the correct behaviour.

I am using material page route for the navigation.

Thanks

[image: Faded Hero]

Comment: add code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fade animation is because of the `MaterialPageRoute` you are using and not because of the `Hero` widget.
This fade animation is the default animation that is rendered when a `MaterialPageRoute` is pushed onto the navigation stack in Flutter.

It is also mentioned in the official [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialPageRoute-class.html).

You can simply use `PageRouteBuilder` if you don't want the fade animation.

Example -

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context, 
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, a1, a2) => MyNewPage(),
    ),
);
```

`a1` and `a2` are the custom animation arguments which can be ignored as you don't require any animation.

Comment: You are correct that the PageRouteBuilder is adding a fade, but if I understand correctly. The "hero" animation should keep the hero widget overlay above the animation and fully visible. It is not doing that. I did some further testing. If I remove the hero widget from the listview builder on the loaded page and just stick it directly into a column it works as expected.

Comment: Maybe that's because in the end the `MaterialPageRoute` is a modal route that replaces the entire screen with a transition. Since the `Hero` widget is a part of the screen itself, I think it won't be able take precedence over the page transition animation.